# PAth misdefinition in .bashrc file

Tags: bashrc

It seems I am a newbee in this Ubuntu world. Yet, somehow I think I just blew up my .bashrc file. Eventually I can no longer issue a ls or chmod or any other commands like sudo joe ~/.bashrc or gedit command. As far as I remember it all started when I accidentally dropped off "export PATH=/bin" line off my .bashrc file. Right now I can no longer issue any terminal commands. Is there a way to retrieve back my bashrc file? Or is there any other way of issuing a "joe" command to reach my .bashrc file? I did try the sudo export commands on the terminal but couldnot work out.
Looking forward of your responses in any convenience.

Comment: Regardless of your shell's `PATH`, you can execute commands using their absolute path ex. `/usr/bin/joe ~/.bashrc`. Don't use `sudo` to edit files in `~`.

Comment: Thank you for your life saving response

Comment: Why don't you fix the `.bashrc` or post it here so we can suggest what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you have blown up your `.bashrc`, then you either can repair it, or reset it to how it appears in a default Ubuntu account, as following:

```
/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
```

Also `.profile` and `.bash_logout` can be restored to factory default by copying over the template file in a similar way if needed.

As a newbie in the Linux world, you of course will not wildly use the `sudo` command. You will use that command only to change system settings, and only after you are well informed and know what you are about to do.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for pointing to the obvious that I missed! I updated the answer.